# Change Selected Rows in Service Calendar[CRM2013]

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamics-crm-2013

I would like to change the row, which selected in Service Calendar at OnLoad.
I hope that I can by UserId select row that needed to me. Is there any solutions? 
Thank You.

There is what I talking about >> (http://i3.minus.com/jbxGeMxRATd6Ll.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no supported way to handle selection of a row.